# Passing inherited frames as argument to a procedure

Tags: function, oop, delphi, inheritance, procedure

I have a TPageControl with N amount of TTabSheets in my main form which I use to embed several TFrame descendants.
For the frames I created a "TBaseFrame" from which I derive the individual frames which I want to display in the TabSheets, more or less looks like this...

TBaseFrame = class(TFrame)

- TBaseFrameDescendant1 = class(TBaseFrame)
- TBaseFrameDescendant2 = class(TBaseFrame)
- TBaseFrameDescendantN = class(TBaseFrame)

**What im struggleing with is this:** I want to create a procedure that takes any of my TBaseFrameDescendants as an argument, creates the given frame and displays it in a new tab sheet. I started with something like this...

```
procedure CreateNewTabSheetAndFrame( What do I put here to accept any of my TBaseFrameDescendants? )
var
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;

begin
  TabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(MainPageControl);
  TabSheet.Caption := 'abc';
  TabSheet.PageControl := MainPageControl;

// Here I want to create the given TBaseFrameDescendant, set the Parent to the above TabSheet and so on   
end;
```

Guess my main question here is how to set up my procedure so I can pass in any frame which is derived from my TBaseFrame so I can work with it within the procedure, or am I heading in the wrong direction here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use what is known as a metaclass.

```
type
  TBaseFrameClass = class of TBaseFrame;

procedure TMainForm.CreateNewTabSheetAndFrame(FrameClass: TBaseFrameClass)
var
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;
  Frame: TBaseFrame;
begin
  TabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
  TabSheet.PageControl := MainPageControl;
  Frame := FrameClass.Create(Self);
  Frame.Parent := TabSheet;
end;
```

Make sure that if you declare any constructors in any of your frame classes, that they derive from the virtual constructor introduced in `TComponent`. That is necessary in order for the instantiation via metaclass to invoke the appropriate derived constructor.

Comment: Cheers David, got it working in a few seconds, big thanks! :)